# Implementing a host of a language service

Tags: typescript, languageservice

After reading the *src\services* code, it seems this is the interface any host of a language service must satisfy:

```
//
// Public interface of the host of a language service instance.
//
export interface ILanguageServiceHost extends TypeScript.ILogger {
    getCompilationSettings(): TypeScript.CompilationSettings;
    getScriptCount(): number;
    getScriptId(scriptIndex: number): string;
    getScriptSourceText(scriptIndex: number, start: number, end: number): string;
    getScriptSourceLength(scriptIndex: number): number;
    getScriptIsResident(scriptIndex: number): bool;
    getScriptVersion(scriptIndex: number): number;
    getScriptEditRangeSinceVersion(scriptIndex: number, scriptVersion: number): TypeScript.ScriptEditRange;
}
```

I haven't been able to find any documentation or samples, and while some methods are self-explanatory, others are not, notably:

```
getScriptId()
getScriptIsResident()
getScriptVersion()
getScriptEditRangeSinceVersion()
```

Is the language service API ready for use? Could someone explain briefly the purpose of the methods above?

Comment: I defer to @RyanCavanaugh on this one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: The language service hosting API will be changing in future versions. I'm not sure what the full extent of the changes will be -- I expect things will be mostly the same, but there will almost certainly be breaking changes.

Also, there's a full TypeScript implementation of the hosting API in `src\harness\harness.ts` used for the language service unit tests you can refer to. Here's a conceptual breakdown of the functions you listed:

`getScriptId()`

You need to return a string that is unique for each file (script), but doesn't change from invocation from invocation. Returning the filename of the script would work nicely.

`getScriptIsResident()`

The compiler has a notion of a 'resident' file that isn't mutable (for example, lib.d.ts). Resident status is used for performance reasons -- for example, types that came out of a resident file are considered immutable (this is why you see oddness in Visual Studio when you try to extend a type defined in lib.d.ts). You can safely return `false` for all files here, or if you know a file is immutable, you can return `true`. The concept of a 'resident' file will go away in some future version of the compiler once the improved type-checker comes online.

`getScriptVersion()`

Here, you need to return a monotonically increasing number that is incremented whenever the source text of the script changes. The language service uses this number to determine whether or not it should do reparsing / retypechecking of the files.

`getScriptEditRangeSinceVersion()`

This function should return a list of edit ranges (hopefully self-explanatory) that have occurred between now and the specified prior version number (see above `getScriptVersion`). Obviously this is a bit of a pain to implement, but it is allowable here to return `TypeScript.ScriptEditRange.unknown()`, at which point the language service will do a full reparse of the file (significant perf impact, so try to do this sparingly in interactive contexts).